# pipe character not recognized in fscanf function

Tags: c

Using c, I am trying to read a file where each variable is delimited by the pipe character. I tried the following

```
fscanf(fp, "%s[|], %s[|], \n", str1, str2);
```

where that character between the brackets is the vertical line: the pipe character.
It can be found on many keyboards above the character `\`.

The incoming string does not split on the pipe character, and the entire string is in `str1`.
What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: what's the content in your file?

Comment: Why not `strtok()` ?

Comment: I haven't tested the problem; but, a pipe char is a special char, so probably needs to be escaped with '\' to be properly recognized

Comment: Post some sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only *appears* OP wants to scan lines given the `'\n'` in the format.
This answer is tailored for reading lines.

When reading lines, best to start with `fgets()`

```
char buf[4096];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp) == NULL) {
  Handle_EOForIOError();
}
```

Then scan it.  Could use `strtok()`, simple code or `sscanf()`.  With `sscanf()`, use width limits and `"%n"` to test the end.

```
char str1[100];
char str2[100];
int n = 0;
sscanf(buf, "%99[^|]|,%99[^|]|, %n", str1, str2, &n);
// n will only have a non-zero if the entire format matched
if (n == 0 || buf[n] != '\0') {
  Handle_scan_failure();
}
```

---

Why `fscanf(fp, "%s[|], %s[|], \n", str1, str2);` has troubles

OP appears to be mixing format specifiers `"%[...]"` and `"%s"`.

`"%s"`  will  skip leading white-spaces and then scan non-space.  Unfortunately it can go on past the space available, best to use a limit like: `char s1[100]; ...  "%99s" ...`

`[|]"` will math only the 3 `char "[|]"`.  Likle OP wants to match a single `|`.

`" \n"` does not match a single space and then a single `'\n'`.  Instead both casue `scanf()` to do the same thing: skip any number of white-space.

Comment: From [this manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf): _The C standard says: "Execution of a %n directive does not increment the assignment count returned at the completion of execution" but the Corrigendum seems to contradict this. Probably it is wise not to make any assumptions on the effect of %n conversions on the return value._ I don't know, how much this is an issue, but maybe switch to `if (2 > sscanf ...`

Comment: @mafso interesting comment.  The C11 spec is quite clear "Execution of a %n directive does not increment the assignment count returned at the completion of execution of the fscanf function."  Your suggestion ( >= 2) would work well in this case, but in other applications of it may not.

Comment: @mafso Reworked to negate testing the return value of `sscanf()`.

Comment: So does C99 TC2 draft (n1124) and C99 TC3 draft (n1256); I can't find the drafts for original C99 and TC1, though. And I'd be more interested if there exist common implementations following the wrong specs.

Answer (score 3):

In a `scanf` format, `%s` means "match any sequence of characters not including whitespace", so my guess is that your file does not include any whitespace.

To match a single <kbd>|</kbd>, you can just insert a <kbd>|</kbd> into the format, because in a scanf format any character other than whitespace and <kbd>%</kbd> matches itself. (That includes <kbd>[</kbd>.) However, each format is independent of any other format, so `%s|` would not mean "match any string up to a <kbd>|</kbd>". It would mean "match any string not including whitespace, and then a <kbd>|</kbd>".

If you want to match any string not containing a <kbd>|</kbd>, you need `%[^|]`. Note that this, like any other format specifier, starts with a <kbd>%</kbd>; without the <kbd>%</kbd>, it would match the literal string `[^|]`.

As always with `scanf` and friends, you need to think about buffer overruns. There is a lot of advice about always using a maximum width, but if you have a Posix 2008-compatible standard library (as with any not terribly ancient `glibc`), then you can use the `m` qualifier to get `scanf` to allocate an appropriately-sized memory region for you. In order to use this, you need to supply the address of a *pointer to* a buffer pointer, instead of a buffer pointer, and you have to remember to free() the supplied buffer pointer when you are done with it, to avoid leaking memory. For example, you might do something like this:

```
int main() {
  char* str1;
  char* str2;
  // Processing loop
  for (;;) {
    str1 = str2 = NULL; // Be safe
    // This reads the variable before the first | into str1 and the rest
    // of the line into str2. %*c will skip over the newline character.
    int rc = scanf("%m[^|]|%m[^\n]%*c", &str1, &str2);
    if (rc == EOF) break;
    if (rc != 2) {
      // Handle error
      printf("Found %d values\n", rc);
    } else {
      // Do something with the strings
      printf("s1=%s\ns2=%s\n", str1, str2);
    }
    // Free the allocated buffers
    free(str1); free(str2);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Finally, a bit of advice: *always* check the return value of `scanf` (as above). That will tell you how many of the patterns matched; if it is less than the number of patterns, you know something went wrong.

Comment: You beat me to the answer by 8 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You just remove the `[]` before and after the `|`.

```
   `fscanf(fp, "%s |, %s |, \n", str1, str2);`
```

Now the content will be stored in str1 and str2.
Because `[|]` it will take as a delimiter as a whole. If the [|] delimiter is present in the file it will read the string.
If there are no white spaces in the input file You can use,

```
   `fscanf(fp, "%[^|] |, %[^|] \n", str1, str2));`
```

It will get the string till the |, while reading the next string the starting character will be | so the condition will be false, so you have to specify the | before reading the next string.

Comment: this is not correct, as the %s conversion knows nothing about | so will continue to input characters until a white space char.

Comment: @user3629249 if the white space is there between the sting we can use without escaping the |. but if there are no white space we have to escape. I accept your comment.